# Link the Side Drawer and Bottom Drawer to contain same screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, expo-router

I want to have a Sidedrawer with Screen1, Sceen 2 and Screen 3 and At the same time BottomDrawer with creen1, Sceen 2 and Screen 3. Both the drawer should be present in Screen1, Sceen 2 and Screen 3.
BottomTabNavigator

```
import React from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Screen1 from '../screens/Screen1';
import Screen2 from '../screens/Screen2';
import Screen3 from '../screens/Screen3';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const BottomTabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Screen3" component={Screen3} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default BottomTabNavigator;
```

SideDrawerNavigator.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import Screen1 from '../screens/Screen1';
import Screen2 from '../screens/Screen2';
import Screen3 from '../screens/Screen3';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const SideDrawerNavigator = () => (
  <Drawer.Navigator>
    <Drawer.Screen name="Screen 1" component={Screen1} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="Screen 2" component={Screen2} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="Screen 3" component={Screen3} />
  </Drawer.Navigator>
);

export default SideDrawerNavigator;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import BottomTabNavigator from './navigation/BottomTabNavigator'; // Import your bottom navigation
import SideDrawerNavigator from './navigation/SideDrawerNavigator'; // Import your side navigation

const App = () => (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <BottomTabNavigator /> {/* Include your bottom navigation */}
    <SideDrawerNavigator /> Include your side navigation
  </NavigationContainer>
);

export default App;
```

I want to have a Sidedrawer with Screen1, Sceen 2 and Screen 3 and At the same time BottomDrawer with creen1, Sceen 2 and Screen 3. Both the drawer should be present in Screen1, Sceen 2 and Screen 3.
BottomTabNavigator

Answer (score 0):

`NavigationContainer` cannot have multiple navigators registered to it. `Tabs` must be nested. Something like this:

```
function Tabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Tabs} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Naturally `Tabs` are not visible when `Settings` are accessed from `Drawer`.